# Как можно уменьшить количество строк кода JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при клике на строку появлялась картинка. Написал код, работает все как нужно, но слишком много строк, помогите пожалуйста оптимизировать его.

Вот что у меня вышло: https://codepen.io/bogdan12315/pen/royYZB

```js
let tab1 = document.getElementById('tab1'),
    tab2 = document.getElementById('tab2'),
    tab3 = document.getElementById('tab3'),
    tab4 = document.getElementById('tab4'),
    tab5 = document.getElementById('tab5'),
    tab6 = document.getElementById('tab6'),
    tab7 = document.getElementById('tab7'),
    tab8 = document.getElementById('tab8'),
    tabimg1 = document.getElementById('demoimg-1'),
    tabimg2 = document.getElementById('demoimg-2'),
    tabimg3 = document.getElementById('demoimg-3'),
    tabimg4 = document.getElementById('demoimg-4'),
    tabimg5 = document.getElementById('demoimg-5'),
    tabimg6 = document.getElementById('demoimg-6'),
    tabimg7 = document.getElementById('demoimg-7'),
    tabimg8 = document.getElementById('demoimg-8');

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    tab1.addEventListener('click', () => {

        tabimg1.style.display = 'block';
        tabimg2.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg3.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg4.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg5.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg6.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg7.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg8.style.display = 'none';

        tab1.classList.add('active');
        tab2.classList.remove('active');
        tab3.classList.remove('active');
        tab4.classList.remove('active');
        tab5.classList.remove('active');
        tab6.classList.remove('active');
        tab7.classList.remove('active');
        tab8.classList.remove('active');

    });

    tab2.addEventListener('click', () => {

        tabimg1.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg2.style.display = 'block';
        tabimg3.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg4.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg5.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg6.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg7.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg8.style.display = 'none';

        tab1.classList.remove('active');
        tab2.classList.add('active');
        tab3.classList.remove('active');
        tab4.classList.remove('active');
        tab5.classList.remove('active');
        tab6.classList.remove('active');
        tab7.classList.remove('active');
        tab8.classList.remove('active');
    });

    tab3.addEventListener('click', () => {

        tabimg1.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg2.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg3.style.display = 'block';
        tabimg4.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg5.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg6.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg7.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg8.style.display = 'none';

        tab1.classList.remove('active');
        tab2.classList.remove('active');
        tab3.classList.add('active');
        tab4.classList.remove('active');
        tab5.classList.remove('active');
        tab6.classList.remove('active');
        tab7.classList.remove('active');
        tab8.classList.remove('active');
    });

    tab4.addEventListener('click', () => {

        tabimg1.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg2.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg3.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg4.style.display = 'block';
        tabimg5.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg6.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg7.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg8.style.display = 'none';

        tab1.classList.remove('active');
        tab2.classList.remove('active');
        tab3.classList.remove('active');
        tab4.classList.add('active');
        tab5.classList.remove('active');
        tab6.classList.remove('active');
        tab7.classList.remove('active');
        tab8.classList.remove('active');
    });

    tab5.addEventListener('click', () => {

        tabimg1.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg2.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg3.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg4.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg5.style.display = 'block';
        tabimg6.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg7.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg8.style.display = 'none';

        tab1.classList.remove('active');
        tab2.classList.remove('active');
        tab3.classList.remove('active');
        tab4.classList.remove('active');
        tab5.classList.add('active');
        tab6.classList.remove('active');
        tab7.classList.remove('active');
        tab8.classList.remove('active');
    });

    tab6.addEventListener('click', () => {

        tabimg1.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg2.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg3.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg4.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg5.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg6.style.display = 'block';
        tabimg7.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg8.style.display = 'none';

        tab1.classList.remove('active');
        tab2.classList.remove('active');
        tab3.classList.remove('active');
        tab4.classList.remove('active');
        tab5.classList.remove('active');
        tab6.classList.add('active');
        tab7.classList.remove('active');
        tab8.classList.remove('active');
    });

    tab7.addEventListener('click', () => {

        tabimg1.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg2.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg3.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg4.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg5.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg6.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg7.style.display = 'block';
        tabimg8.style.display = 'none';

        tab1.classList.remove('active');
        tab2.classList.remove('active');
        tab3.classList.remove('active');
        tab4.classList.remove('active');
        tab5.classList.remove('active');
        tab6.classList.remove('active');
        tab7.classList.add('active');
        tab8.classList.remove('active');
    });

    tab8.addEventListener('click', () => {

        tabimg1.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg2.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg3.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg4.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg5.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg6.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg7.style.display = 'none';
        tabimg8.style.display = 'block';

        tab1.classList.remove('active');
        tab2.classList.remove('active');
        tab3.classList.remove('active');
        tab4.classList.remove('active');
        tab5.classList.remove('active');
        tab6.classList.remove('active');
        tab7.classList.remove('active');
        tab8.classList.add('active');
    });

});
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.content{
  display: flex;
}

.active {
  color: #40babd;
}

.tab-pane {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  display: none;
}
.tab-pane:nth-child(1) {
  background: black;
  display: block;
}
.tab-pane:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}
.tab-pane:nth-child(3) {
  background: yellow;
}
.tab-pane:nth-child(4) {
  background: gray;
}
.tab-pane:nth-child(5) {
  background: purple;
}
.tab-pane:nth-child(6) {
  background: blue;
}
.tab-pane:nth-child(7) {
  background: orange;
}
.tab-pane:nth-child(8) {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" id="tab1" >Управління даними</a></li>
      <li><a class="" id="tab2" >Вибір частини тіла</a></li>
      <li><a class="" id="tab3" >Вибір органу</a></li>
      <li><a class="" id="tab4" >Перед експозиція</a></li>
      <li><a class="" id="tab5" >Експозиція</a></li>
      <li><a class="" id="tab6" >Отримання</a></li>
      <li><a class="" id="tab7" >Обробка</a></li>
      <li><a class="" id="tab8" >Завантаження</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>


<div class="tab-panes">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="demoimg-1"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="demoimg-2"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="demoimg-3"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="demoimg-4"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="demoimg-5"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="demoimg-6"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="demoimg-7"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="demoimg-8"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: используйте общие классы вместо частных id и будет вам счастье

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let content = document.querySelector(".content"),
      tabs = content.querySelector(".tabs > ul"),
      tabPanes = content.querySelector(".tab-panes"),
      last = 0;

  for (let i = 0, len = tabs.children.length; i < len; i++) {
    tabs.children[i].addEventListener('click', event => {
      tabs.children[last].classList.remove("active");
      tabPanes.children[last].style.display = "none";
      last = i;
      tabs.children[last].classList.add("active");
      tabPanes.children[last].style.display = "block";
    })
  }
});
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
}

.active {
  color: #40babd;
}

.tab-pane {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  display: none;
}

.tab-pane:nth-child(1) {
  background: black;
  display: block;
}

.tab-pane:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}

.tab-pane:nth-child(3) {
  background: yellow;
}

.tab-pane:nth-child(4) {
  background: gray;
}

.tab-pane:nth-child(5) {
  background: purple;
}

.tab-pane:nth-child(6) {
  background: blue;
}

.tab-pane:nth-child(7) {
  background: orange;
}

.tab-pane:nth-child(8) {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a>Управління даними</a></li>
      <li><a>Вибір частини тіла</a></li>
      <li><a>Вибір органу</a></li>
      <li><a>Перед експозиція</a></li>
      <li><a>Експозиція</a></li>
      <li><a>Отримання</a></li>
      <li><a>Обробка</a></li>
      <li><a>Завантаження</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-panes">
    <div class="tab-pane"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const tabElements = document.getElementsByClassName('tab');
const tabPaneElements = document.getElementsByClassName('tab-pane');

const tabs = [...tabElements];
const tabPanes = [...tabPaneElements];

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  tabs.forEach((tab, i) => {
    tab.addEventListener("click", () => {
      setActiveItemFromList(tabs, i, "active");
      setActiveItemFromList(tabPanes, i, "active-pane");
    })
  })
})

const setActiveItemFromList = (arr, i, className) => {
  arr.forEach((el, l) => {
    if (l === i) {
      el.classList.add(className);
    } else {
      el.classList.remove(className);
    }
  })
};
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.content{
  display: flex;
}

.active {
  color: #40babd;
}

.tab-pane {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  display: none;
}

.active-pane {
  display: block;
}

.active-pane.tab-pane:nth-child(1) {
  background: black;
}
.active-pane.tab-pane:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}
.active-pane.tab-pane:nth-child(3) {
  background: yellow;
}
.active-pane.tab-pane:nth-child(4) {
  background: gray;
}
.active-pane.tab-pane:nth-child(5) {
  background: purple;
}
.active-pane.tab-pane:nth-child(6) {
  background: blue;
}
.active-pane.tab-pane:nth-child(7) {
  background: orange;
}
.active-pane.tab-pane:nth-child(8) {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="tabs">
    <ul>
    <li><a class="tab" >Управління даними</a></li>
    <li><a class="tab active" >Вибір частини тіла</a></li>
    <li><a class="tab" >Вибір органу</a></li>
    <li><a class="tab" >Перед експозиція</a></li>
    <li><a class="tab" >Експозиція</a></li>
    <li><a class="tab" >Отримання</a></li>
    <li><a class="tab" >Обробка</a></li>
    <li><a class="tab" >Завантаження</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>


<div class="tab-panes">
    <div class="tab-pane" ></div>
    <div class="tab-pane active-pane" ></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" ></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" ></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" ></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" ></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" ></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" ></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Как сказал [@Георгий Чеботарев](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/242834/%d0%93%d0%b5%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%a7%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2)

> используйте общие классы вместо частных id и будет вам счастье